# Why this function definition from a curried function doesn't work in scala?

Tags: scala, currying

I'm going through Odersky's course of functional programming in scala.

The **currying** function definition style in scala is:

```
def f(arg1)(arg2)....(argn) = E
```

It's shown to be equivalent to

```
def f = (arg1 => (arg2 => ...(argn => E)...))
```

according to the course.

What confuse me is that why this function definition doesn't work ?

```
    def sumOf(f: Int => Int)(a: Int, b: Int): Int = {
      if (a > b) 0 else f(a) + sumOf(f)(a + 1, b)
    }
    // doesn't compile
    def sumOfDouble = sumOf(x => x * 2)
```

Since it's common case in other language like **js**:

```
    const sum = fn => (a, b) => (a > b) ? 0 : fn(a) + sum(fn)(a + 1, b);
    const sumOfDouble = sum(x => x * 2);
    sumOfDouble(1, 10); // => 110
```

What confuse me more is that:

```
      def sumbOf =
        (f: Int => Int) =>
          (a: Int, b: Int) =>
            (
                if (a > b) 0 else f(a) + sumbOf(f)(a + 1, b)
            )
      // this works
      def sumOfDouble = sumbOf(x => x * 2)
      sumOfDouble(1, 10) // => 110
```

So what's happening here, these two forms of definition don't seems to be equivalent?

If so, what's the difference ?

Comment: The first version is looking for 2 set of parameters. so `def sumOfDouble = sumOf(x => x * 2)(1,10)` would work, but since you're only providing partial information, hence it is not compiling.

Comment: if you want partially applied function, then do `def sum1 = sumOf(x => x*2) _` and `def sum2 = sum1(1,10)`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct, except that `def` methods are not exactly equivalent to function values: the `def` is a method, not a value with type `X => Y`.

The Scala compiler will indeed lift the unapplied method into a function value, but only when such a value is expected. This means that the compiler has to be sure that this "conversion to function value" is what you expect. It will happen seamlessly as soon as you provide an explicit type. For example, this would be the case you were passing `sumOf(x => x * 2)` to another method expecting a `(Int, Int) => Int`. In the case of your declaration of `sumOfDouble`, you only have to be a bit more explicit and the following examples will work just fine:

```
// Explicit lifting into a function value
def sumOfDouble = sumOf(x => x * 2)(_, _)

// Explicit type to "force" the conversion
def sumOfDouble: (Int, Int) => Int = sumOf(x => x * 2) 

// shorthand for the 1st example, but works for any number of parameters
def sumOfDouble = sumOf(x => x * 2) _
```

Comment: Thanks, this make sense as I realized (unapplied) methods and functions are different things.

Answer (score 1):

> def sumOfDouble = sumOf(x => x * 2)

In this case you're only applying the method to one argument but the method expects two. If you want to apply only one and use it as an anonymous function, you can pass it as an parameter to higher order function. See `modN` function [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/currying.html)

> ```
>   def sumOfDouble = sumbOf(x => x * 2)
> ```

This works because it returns a function that accepts a function and returns a function that accepts two parameters and applies that method to those parameters.

In this case first case is currying while second case is more closely related to [higher order functions](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/higher-order-functions.html)

Hope this helps. Please repond if you do not understand.